# Declare a variable in Oracle SQL to use in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, select, declare

Hi I am trying to declare a variable to use in Oracle SQL select query as such:

```
DECLARE 
  myDate DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT Source as "Source", DT as "Date", Status as "Status", COALESCE("Count", 0) as "Count"
FROM (Huge SubQuery that includes many WHERE date between x and y);
END;
```

I need to use myDate for the query so I dont have to update it in 10 places everytime I run the query.  Basically its just for declaring a variable that can be used in a where date is between clause in several places.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error(2,7): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710471/error2-7-pls-00428-an-into-clause-is-expected-in-this-select-statement) - see Alex Poole's answer

Comment: Don't use a PL/SQL block. Simply use a bind variable. Go to Oracle Docs for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm

Comment: It is not clear where you want to initialize and use myDate. Can you update your question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring & Setting Variables in a Select Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400058/declaring-setting-variables-in-a-select-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
variable var DATE
exec :var := '15-OCT-13'
```

and then your select with using :var in it

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to add variables for the sql query as follows

```
DEFINE RES_DT = TO_DATE('11-AUG-15');
```

And also to access the variable through the query we have to use '&' notation as follows

```
select * from customer where assign_date = &RES_DT;
```

Comment: Are you using Query Manager? Or is this just plain SQL?

Comment: Yes It is plain SQL